# llvm openmp: what is the meaning of internal, thread_local, unnamed_addr, global in variable declarations?

Tags: llvm, openmp

In the llvm IR of an openmp code we see internal, thread_local, unnamed_addr, global etc. associated with variable declarations. Here is a sample:

```
@count = internal thread_local unnamed_addr global [64 x i32] zeroinitializer, align 16
```

What is the meaning of them and the difference between them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the LLVM language reference, this is [the format of a global variable](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables):

```
[@<GlobalVarName> =] [Linkage] [Visibility] [DLLStorageClass] [ThreadLocal]
                     [unnamed_addr] [AddrSpace] [ExternallyInitialized]
                     <global | constant> <Type> [<InitializerConstant>]
                     [, section "name"] [, comdat [($name)]]
                     [, align <Alignment>]
```

That guide also has an explanation of what each means. Specifically in this case, a **simplified** explanation of the parts of

```
@count = internal thread_local unnamed_addr global [64 x i32] zeroinitializer, align 16
```

Is:

- `count` - The global's name.
- `internal` - Only accessible in current module.
- `thread_local` - Each thread gets its own copy of this variable.
- `unnamed_addr` - The global's address is never accessed (this is useful for some optimizations).
- `global` - It's a global variable (this isn't a modifier, this is what this statement is).
- `zeroinitializer` - The global's memory is initialized with zeroes.
- `align 16` - The global's address with be 16-aligned (divisible by 16).

In general, if you're trying to understand any piece of LLVM IR, [the language reference guide](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) is **the** place to start.